# Statistics software for Mac and Windows

Tags: windows, osx, statistics

I am looking for a software package that will run on both Windows and Mac OS and let me quickly generate and visualize basic descriptive statistics about my data and do simple regressions.

My data is tabular; most sets are a few million records and all can fit in memory.

I have been using Python with Pandas, the rest of the SciPy stack, and Jupyter notebooks.  While I love Python in general, I find it can be a little cumbersome to quickly explore a dataset--I'm sure there will be those that disagree with me, but after a couple years of use this is my current opinion.

I'm looking for a package that emphasis ease of use, speed, and interactivity.  Again primarily basic descriptive statistics.  And, I can always fall back to Python if there are edge cases it doesn't support.

Generally I am happy to pay more if the product warrants it, but would like to try and keep the cost around or under $1,500 for a perpetual license.

Comment: What about R and/or the R bindings for various programming languages, including Python... ?

Answer (score 1):

Airbnb's Superset looks like a really nice exploration tool.  It is built with Python and is open source:

https://github.com/airbnb/superset